# C#.Net RestSharp client - passing auth token

Tags: rest, api, restsharp

I am writing a REST client in C#.Net using RestSharp. There are two API calls - one is "Auth" call and second is "getKey" call. The "Auth" call throws back a "Auth token"in the response, and I'd like to parse that token from the response, and pass it as an header to the second "getkey" call. Please advise with examples

Answer (score 0):

I have given some sample to achieve your scenario. Please use the below example and do the modification as per your requirement.

**RestUtils Class:**

Add the Request Header, If your application is expected some additional headers.

```
 class RestUtils
    {
        private static readonly RestClient _restClient = new RestClient();

        public static void SetBaseURL(String host)
        {
            _restClient.BaseUrl = new Uri(host);
        }

        public static string GetResponse(String endpoint, String token)
        {
            var request = new RestRequest(endpoint, Method.GET);
            request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", token);
            IRestResponse response = _restClient.Execute(request);
            return response.Content;
        }

        public static string GetToken(String endpoint)
        {
            var request = new RestRequest(endpoint, Method.GET);
            request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            IRestResponse response = _restClient.Execute(request);
            return response.Content;
        }
    }
```

**TestClass:**

In your test class you can add the below steps and you can get the result as expected. First two lines will be executed and give the authentication token as output. So, you can use the retrieved token in the subsequent lines for other API. In another way, you can create one property class and set the retrieved token value .So, that you can access the token from various class.

```
        //Specify the Base URI of your Token Specific API
        RestUtils.SetBaseURL("https://login.microsoftonline.com/");
        //Specify the End Point of your Token Specific API
        String token = RestUtils.GetToken("/oauth2/token");

        //Specify the Base URI of your actual Test API
        RestUtils.SetBaseURL("XXXXXXX");
        String response = RestUtils.GetResponse(token);
```